# Почему парсер выдает ошибку 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

```
File "avitoeng.py", line 28, in get_page_data
    ads = soup.find('div', class_='catalog-main').find('div', 
    class_='catalog-list').find_all('div', class_='item')  AttributeError: 
   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

[image: in console, all work]
[image: website have this tags]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_total_pages(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    pages = soup.find('div', class_='pagination-pages').find_all('a', class_='pagination-page')[-1].get('href')
    # find div, class = pagination-pages, a, class = pagination-pages,take list and last element , href
    # получили '/moskva/telefony?p=60&q=htc'

    total_pages = pages.split('=')[1].split('&')[0]
    # split to "=" and get last page

    return int(total_pages)

def write_csv(data):
    with open('avito.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer  = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow( (data['title'],data['price'],data['metro'],data['url']) )

def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    ads = soup.find('div', class_='catalog-main').find('div', class_='catalog-list').find_all('div', class_='item') 
    #get list all ads

    for ad in ads:
        try:
            title = ad.find('div', class_='description').find('h3').text.strip()
        # get title
        except: 
            title = 'none'
        try:
            url = 'https://www.avito.ru' + ad.find('div', class_='description').find('a').get('href')
        # get url
        except:
            url = ' none '
        try:
            price = ad.find('div', class_='description').find('div', class_='about').text.strip()
        # get price
        except:
            price = 'none'
        try:
            metro = 'м.' + ad.find('div', class_='description').find('div', class_='data').find('p').text.split()[1]
        # get metro
        except:
            metro = 'none'

        data = {'title': title,'price': price,'metro': metro,'url': url} # словарь со всеми данными

        write_csv(data)

def main():
    url ='https://www.avito.ru/moskva/telefony?p=61&q=htc'
    base_url ='https://www.avito.ru/moskva/telefony'
    page_part = 'p='
    query_part = '&q=htc'

    total_pages = get_total_pages(get_html(url)) 
    # total_pages получает html в результате работы get_html, которому передаем аргумент url

    for i in range(1, total_pages):
        url_gen = base_url + page_part + str(i) + query_part # сгенерировали все урлы
        # print(url_gen)
        html = get_html(url_gen)
        get_page_data(html)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Заверните место возникновение ошибки в try-except, добавьте вывод содержмого полученной страницы и убедитесь, что в нём присутствуют элементы удовлетворяющие селектору

```
try:
    ads = (soup.find('div', class_='catalog-main')
               .find('div', class_='catalog-list')
               .find_all('div', class_='item'))
except AttributeError:
    print(html)
```

Вполне возможно, что платформа замечает парсинг и начинает выдавать вам заглушку.

Comment: ок. я попробовал написать парсер на другой сайт  https://bash.im , но там возникает та же проблема. как мне обойти это распознавание парсера

Comment: Парсеры палятся на том, что ведут себя как роботы. Люди не обходят все доступные ссылки, только некоторое подмножество без ухода на большую глубину. Чтобы не попасться, надо изобразить группу людей шарящихся по сайту. Для этого надо после разбора страницы входа парсить только две-три ссылки с неё, делать случайные паузы между запросами, потом сбрасывать принятые куки, менять user agent и прокси и парсить другие две-три ссылки. Естественно, прокси не должны быть публичными. Если вы могли найти и скачать их список, то разработчики защиты тоже уже его скачали.

Comment: если я запускаю комманды через консоль .все работает, но в sublima, нет. Я уже открыл тему по вопросу на тостере .можете посмотреть комментарии. пожалуйста.

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/538884  - ссылка на тему на тостере

Comment: Попробуйте find_all

Comment: @Александр вы о чём? У меня и так используется `find_all`.

Comment: А простите не внимателен устал за день )